# How to pack a 32 bit into 4x8 bit?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, byte

I am fairly new to C programming and I am sorry, if the explanation of the problem is unsatisfactory. I have a 32 bit binary number as follows:

```
typedef unsigned long U32;
U32 a;
a = 11111111000000001111111100000000;
```

How can I convert that into 4 times 8 bit binary numbers. I just want to take the first 8 bits under a variable and seconds 8 bits into another variable and etc. For example,

```
typedef uint8;
uint8 b, c, d, e;
b = 11111111;
c = 00000000;
d = 11111111;
e = 00000000;
```

Comment: Why not use stdint.h rather than defining your own?

Comment: I made it just for the sake of asking this question. No other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could just apply the correct shift and mask to each variable as per:

```
typedef unsigned long U32;
U32 a;
a = 0xFF00FF00; //11111111000000001111111100000000;

uint8 b, c, d, e;

e = (uint8)(a & 0xFF);
d = (uint8)((a >> 8) & 0xFF);
c = (uint8)((a >> 16) & 0xFF);
b = (uint8)((a >> 24) & 0xFF);
```

That is the quick and dirty way. You could also use a loop to be more elegant.

Comment: @progLeaner Is your solution is general or specific to my example?

Comment: Will work for any "a" value

Comment: @progLeaner In your answer, you mean the `b` as MSB and `e` as LSB right? Also, can I use the same mechanism to pack 48 bit into a 6x8 bit ?

Comment: Yes, same mechanism for 48-bit numbers.
I respected the MSB as per your example, so yes b as MSB and e as LSB.

Comment: @progLeaner Which operand to use? I guess the bitwise `&`? You used `&&`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. Why don't you try and run it in a debugger?